# FQDN Cloudera manager Issue hadoop admin

Tags: hadoop, admin, cloudera-manager

Ques: Cloudera Manager opens web UI links with FQDN name and local networked system can not resolve this name. But short name and ip works.

```
Hostfile:
#::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.xxx.xxx.xx   aster1.com      aster1
10.xxx.xxx.xx   aster4.com      aster4
10.xxx.xxx.xx   aster3.com      aster3
10.xxx.xxx.xx   aster2.com      aster2

JT or anyother hadoop component web UI i am able to open with aster1:8088 but not with FQDN name aster1.com:8088. cloudera manager by default uses FQDN name. is there a way to correct this.

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Do you have this file in sync between all cluster nodes and gateways?

Comment: Yes..it is synced in all the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You might check that you have embedded the hostname in the /etc/sysconfig/network file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do not comment out default network configuration in/etc/hosts file